# NMEA statements appears infinitely in sim808

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm

when I upload the code on arduino mega with sim808 bk-808-v3.1 , I reach the following output on the serial monitor. A NMEA statements appears infinitely.  what is the problem and how to solve it?
Note that i connect SMS antenna and GPS antenna with sim808

[image]

the code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM808(10,11); //(RX-Pin,TX-Pin)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SIM808.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (SIM808.available())
    Serial.write(SIM808.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    SIM808.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know about SIM808. But the GPS module seems to properly outputing NMEA packets every seconds by reading the GPGGA packet.

If the problem is that messages are printed out too slowly, try using `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')` and `Serial.print` functions instead of `Serial.read()` and `Serial.write()` functions.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM808(10,11); //(RX-Pin,TX-Pin)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SIM808.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (SIM808.available())
    Serial.print(SIM808.readStringUntil('\n'));
  if (Serial.available())
    SIM808.print(Serial.readStringUntil('\n'));
}
```